# Need to find & convert thousands of multi-page TIFFs

Tags: pdf, homebrew, preview

I have a large collection of documents in various formats (PDF, TIFF, JPEG).

Many of the TIFFs are multi-page, like faxes, and the only way I know to see all the pages is with Preview.

Is there some **method** or **app** or **shell command** (via `brew`) which can find all the multi-page TIFFs so that I can convert them to multi-page PDFs?

Comment: Are you looking to learn how to program this (so you can decide to hire that work out or do it yourself) or more of a software-recommendation type problem. The programming method is quite broad in itself, and shell / automator / AppleScript might be quite suitable in the hands of someone moderately skilled with those tools.

Comment: I played around bit with [LibTIFF](http://www.libtiff.org) which among the utils are `tiff2pdf` and `tiff2ps`. The former didn't work, just made blank pages, however the latter did work. I then used the native `pstopdf` to convert the .ps files to .pdf files. This can be scripted to deal with multiple input files and removing the intermediary .ps files so what's left are the original .tiff and the converted .pdf files. Your question is somewhat broad so I'm not going to put this in the form of an answer as there is no info about your skill level and what else you need to deal with the issue.

Comment: `tiff2pdf` works for me ... on about 60% of the TIFFs. The rest I can convert with Preview. My issue is identifying them, not converting them. I'll try exiftool.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to find them using a command line in the terminal. This requires you to install a tool which is not part of the default command set.

[Download and install exiftool.](http://owl.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/)

exiftool is able to print detailed information about image files, including TIFFs. It can tell the difference between multi-page documents and between FAXes and photographic TIFFs. For example testphoto.tif is a regular TIFF file and testfax.tif is a multi-page FAX:

```
MacBook-Air:Downloads jamie$ exiftool -s -Format -Compression -SubfileType *.tif 
======== testfax.tif
Compression                     : T6/Group 4 Fax
SubfileType                     : Single page of multi-page image
======== testphoto.tif
Format                          : image/tiff
Compression                     : LZW
SubfileType                     : Full-resolution Image
    2 image files read
```

If we can get the filename and the identifying info on one line, then we can use grep to identify the files we want. The -csv option puts the output on one line in comma seperated value format. So, a command like this would do what you want.

```
MacBook-Air:Downloads jamie$ exiftool -csv  -SubfileType *.tif | grep multi-page
    2 image files read
testfax.tif,Single page of multi-page image
```

So, we have correctly identified testfax.tif as the only multi-page TIFF in this directory.

Comment: You may not be able to rely on exiftool. I have lots of multi-page .tiff files that it doesn't detect as being multi-page, including ones that state T6/Group 4 Fax, are multi-page but doesn't show it. So while it's a possible method it may not be reliable depending on other factors.

Comment: I could believe that, depending on how they were created, attributes could vary.  Perhaps for the OP, it will be sufficient, or perhaps even better, to detect the "T6/Group 4 Fax" attribute.

Comment: How many pages is `testfax.tif` and does `exiftool` give you a `Page Count` for that .tif?

Comment: testfax.tif is three pages. `exiftool -a` actually returns info for each separate page:  `MacBook-Air:Downloads jamie$ exiftool -a testfax.tif | grep -i page
Subfile Type                    : Single page of multi-page image
Page Number                     : 0 3
Subfile Type                    : Single page of multi-page image
Page Number                     : 1 3
Subfile Type                    : Single page of multi-page image
Page Number                     : 2 3`        So, I'm interpreting that as describing the last page, for example as 2 of 3.

Comment: Not working for me ... fails to identify some multipages... :(

Comment: Can you identify any of the many other attributes detected by exiftool that would distinguish the files you want? Or, what about file size? Anything less than a certain size is single page?